# Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 401

Tags: debian, gitlab

Im setting up a GitLab Server on Debian 6x32 manual installation and encountered a problem while checking gitlab installation. Frontend is working fine, but I can't even gain access to repos (tried pushing).

When i run

> sudo -u git bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production

the following output appears

```html
stekotin@rserv /home/git/gitlab $ sudo -u git bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  sudo -u git -H "/usr/bin/git" config --global user.name  "GitLab"
  sudo -u git -H "/usr/bin/git" config --global user.email "git@domain.com"
  sudo -u git -H "/usr/bin/git" config --global core.autocrlf "input"
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "GitLab"
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 2.2.0 ? ... OK (2.2.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
Satellites access is drwxr-x---? ... yes
hooks directories in repos are links: ... 
Mikhail Kuzmin / test ... repository is empty
Daria Efimova / Amway ... repository is empty
Pavel Volobuev / IASBeaconTest ... repository is empty
Nikolay Shubenkov / iBeacon ... repository is empty
Sergei Tekotin / my ... repository is empty
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 401
gitlab-shell self-check failed
  Try fixing it:
  Make sure GitLab is running;
  Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:
  sudo -u git -H editor /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned GroupMembers? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
projects have namespace: ... 
Sergei Tekotin / my ... yes
Projects have satellites? ... 
Mikhail Kuzmin / test ... can't create, repository is empty
Daria Efimova / Amway ... can't create, repository is empty
Pavel Volobuev / IASBeaconTest ... can't create, repository is empty
Nikolay Shubenkov / iBeacon ... can't create, repository is empty
Sergei Tekotin / my ... can't create, repository is empty
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Ruby version >= 2.0.0 ? ... yes (2.1.5)
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.7.10)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

Tried almost every solution found on internet, but none of them worked. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This output tell you to check gitlab-shell config in `/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml`. What about your conf in this file ?